# ListView with embed Gallery, data set to the wrong pointer

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gallery

Hello I'm using Listview with a Base Adapter from an Array.
I use custom rows with two TextViews and a Gallery.

My arrays contains Mission items, which themselves contain a photo array.

My problem is that, when the list loads, everything is good, but actually, the first row now holds the position to the last row, so if I try to scroll my first row gallery it either loads images from the last row or it crashes completely.

And here is the code for my base adapter.
https://gist.github.com/1009976

I guess I should keep a trace of the position in the array for the gallery adapter but I don't know how :/